# Issue with Creating List of Link Labels

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using code as below to create a list of link labels :

```
 LinkLabel[] lnkArray = new LinkLabel[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            lnkArray[i] = new LinkLabel();
            lnkArray[i].Text = "test" + i;
            lnkArray[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20 + (i + 5), 50);
            lnkArray[i].Size = new Size(200, 25);
        }

        panel1.Controls.AddRange(lnkArray);
```

Here is a image of the result :

[image]

It looks good to me but this always makes one linklabel in the panel with text = test0 .So basically it is adding just the first one in the list any solution ?

Comment: I'm confused about your question. Please explain more

Comment: @VigneshKumar let me make a screen shot to under better

Comment: @VigneshKumar see now  , as i make of 10 it only add one to the panel the first one.

Comment: Each label is only 1 pixel further to the right than the last, and they're 200 pixels wide. They're probably just overlapping.

Comment: Try querying the length of the `lnkArray` and see if it's 10 or not

Comment: Oh yes they are... Thank you not sure which one answered first i got them all at once :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem with `AddRange`.
The problem in your code is that the `LinkLabel`(s) is overlapping.
The width of the `LinkLabel` in your code is 200. Therefore, you should leave at least 200px gap between the labels.
Try changing your code to this:-

LinkLabel[] lnkArray = new LinkLabel[10];

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        lnkArray[i] = new LinkLabel();
        lnkArray[i].Text = "test" + i;
        lnkArray[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20 + (i + 200), 50);
        lnkArray[i].Size = new Size(200, 25);
    }

    panel1.Controls.AddRange(lnkArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use this instead of array

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
         LinkLabel lnkLbl = new LinkLabel();
          // add properties i.e Text , Location , size
         panel1.Controls.Add(lnlLbl);
    }
```

Comment: I did actually its the same thing and same results.

Comment: you can change the size , may be another labels are overlapping